# is it possble to use lowdb to update an existing json value?

Tags: node.js

I'm using lowdb https://github.com/typicode/lowdb.
I have a small database that looks like this

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "kit": "not a real order"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "kit": "kit_1"
    }
  ],
  "total orders": 21,
  "216862330724548608": 1
}
```

is it possble to change the `"kit": "x"` to `"kit": "y"`

x and y are user input so I can't just use replace because I don't know what it will be equal to.

I did try to use some kind of replace but it didn't work

Comment: You just want to update your values for `kit`on real time. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Garry kinda I want that if the user runs the command lets say `?update [name]` it will change it into that 
or
if user do `?update [name]` it will change it into [old kit]+[new name]

Comment: how you would define update[newName] or update[name]. You would need a flag for it to define if its a new name. Now question is you are looking for db query or JavaScript code (you already know query)?

Comment: i fixed my code with replace maybe that will give you the idea of what I want to make
https://pastebin.com/raw/GyuGD12n
if you got an idea how I can make it better I'm open to ideas @Garry

Answer (score 0):

```
let = updateOrders = (items, id, newValue) => {
  const {orders} = items;
  orders.map((item) => {
    item.kit = newValue;
    //if you need id check uncomment below code and add id in arguments and pass id
    // if (item.id === id) {
    //    item.kit = newValue;
    // }
  })
  console.log(orders);
};

updateOrders(orders, 'updated');
```

Hopefully it would help.